# Trying to setup a network between Ubuntu and virtualbox

Tags: networking, virtualbox, virtualization

I am running ubuntu on my machine with another ubuntu in Virtualbox, I am trying to make them connect together so they both have access each others and both can access the internet.

This is the `ifconfig` of the host machine

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
    inet 130.15.1.72  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 130.15.1.255
    inet6 fe80::3f37:1632:b494:f83d  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
    ether 84:2b:2b:a2:f0:d2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
    RX packets 7275030  bytes 2419246030 (2.4 GB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 705630  bytes 93740106 (93.7 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
    device interrupt 21  memory 0xf7fe0000-f8000000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
    inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
    inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
    loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
    RX packets 132569  bytes 44162247 (44.1 MB)
    RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
    TX packets 132569  bytes 44162247 (44.1 MB)
    TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And this is the `/etc/network/interfaces` of the host

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

auto eno1
iface eno1 inet static
address 130.15.1.72
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 130.15.1.0
broadcast 130.15.1.255
gateway 130.15.1.1
```

In Virtualbox network settings, I set up a Host only network called `vboxnet0` with the following settings:

```
IP4 Address: 192.168.56.0
IP4 Network Mask: 255.255.255.0
```

and DHCP disabled

Now I have in the virtual machine settings:

```
Adapter 1: Host only network - vboxnet0
Adapter 2: NAT
```

This is the output when I run `ls /sys/class/net` on my guest

> enp0s3    enp0s8    lo

This is the `ifconfig` of the guest machine

```
enp0s3: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.56.101  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.56.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fefd:775c  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:fd:77:5c  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 87  bytes 9096 (9.0 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

enp0s8: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 10.0.3.15  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 10.0.3.255
        inet6 fe80::a00:27ff:fef3:976  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 08:00:27:f3:09:76  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 14384  bytes 13692205 (13.6 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 6941  bytes 749919 (749.9 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 348  bytes 25732 (25.7 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 348  bytes 25732 (25.7 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

And this is the `/etc/network/interfaces`

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback

# The host-only network interface
auto enp0s3
iface enp0s3 inet static
address 192.168.56.101
netmask 255.255.255.0
network 192.168.56.0
broadcast 192.168.56.255

# NAT interface
auto enp0s8
iface enp0s8 inet dhcp
```

I am trying to ping to make sure the connectivity is established. The guest seems to be able to ping the host (130.15.1.72) successfully. However, the host can only ping 192.168.56.0 (which is just the broadcast address for vboxnet0), while pinging 192.168.56.101 just hangs without giving any output.
Also, when I try to SSH from the host, I just get

> Trying 192.168.56.101...

While when I try to SSH from the guest I get a connection refused error.

Please help me and let me know what I'm doing wrong. I am sure it's something in the IP addresses because it was very confusing for me to set up.

Thanks

Comment: You just need to have one network adapter for virtual machine in network settings and make it bridged. And that's it!

Comment: Thanks for the comment.
I tried that and it didn't work; First, I lost internet connectivity on the guest side, and neither the guest or the host was able to ping each others

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After several days of continuous research, and trial and error. I finally managed to solve the issue, and I can't believe how simple it was...

My problem was solved by simply updating virtualbox to the latest version!
I just ran

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get upgrade
```

VirtualBox should be closed before running this command, or else it will fail to update obviously. After this, I just restarted my host machine, and that did it! my `ifconfig` was automatically fixed to show the new interface (vboxnet0), which I was never able to see before:

```
eno1: flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 130.15.1.72  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 130.15.1.255
        inet6 fe80::862b:2bff:fea2:f0d2  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 84:2b:2b:a2:f0:d2  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 45609  bytes 25862185 (25.8 MB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 16778  bytes 2427180 (2.4 MB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
        device interrupt 21  memory 0xf7fe0000-f8000000  

lo: flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING>  mtu 65536
        inet 127.0.0.1  netmask 255.0.0.0
        inet6 ::1  prefixlen 128  scopeid 0x10<host>
        loop  txqueuelen 1000  (Local Loopback)
        RX packets 1222  bytes 239666 (239.6 KB)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 1222  bytes 239666 (239.6 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

vboxnet0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.56.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.56.255
        inet6 fe80::800:27ff:fe00:0  prefixlen 64  scopeid 0x20<link>
        ether 0a:00:27:00:00:00  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 608  bytes 60421 (60.4 KB)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0

virbr0: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST>  mtu 1500
        inet 192.168.122.1  netmask 255.255.255.0  broadcast 192.168.122.255
        ether 52:54:00:43:82:ee  txqueuelen 1000  (Ethernet)
        RX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        RX errors 0  dropped 0  overruns 0  frame 0
        TX packets 0  bytes 0 (0.0 B)
        TX errors 0  dropped 0 overruns 0  carrier 0  collisions 0
```

Now I simply started the guest and sure enough, I was finally able to ping back and forth :)
One mistake I was doing though, I thought that (130.15.1.72) should be used to ping the host. That's wrong; the address that was used to setup vboxnet0 in virtualbox network settings should be used by the guests to communicate with the host. Therefore, I set the vboxnet0 settings as follows:

```
IP4 Address: 192.168.56.1
IP4 Network Mask: 255.255.255.0
```

All the other settings are left unbranched from my previous post. And now I can ping the host from the guest(s) by:

```
ping 192.168.56.1
```

And I can ping the guests by running

```
ping 192.168.56.101
```

Or whatever their static IP is set to be.

Hope this helps anyone else if they got stuck at this, it's really frustrating!

And thanks for whoever read my post

Comment: VirtualBox Version: 5.1.26 r117224 (Qt5.7.1)

Answer (score 0):

> ```
> wlp0s20f3: flags = 4099 <UP, BROADCAST, MULTICAST>
> ```

I have achieved success with the following commands regarding the mtu 1500 solution and it works flawlessly.

---

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-hwe-team/backport-iwlwifi
cd backport-iwlwifi/

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical

sudo add-apt-repository ppa:canonical-hwe-team

sudo apt-get update sudo apt-get install backport-iwlwifi-dkms

sudo apt-get install backport-iwlwifi-dkms
  

  

sudo apt-get remove backport-iwlwifi-dkms
cat /etc/apt/sources.list

   

 

iwconfig

dmesg | grep iwl

git clone https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware

   

 cd linux-firmware/

  

  

make

sudo modprobe iwlwifi
  

  

sudo modprobe iwl4965

sudo rmmod iwlmvm iwlwifi

sudo make install
   

sudo make
cat /etc/apt/sources.list

sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
   

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 40976EAF437D05B5
   

sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 3B4FE6ACC0B21F32
sudo apt-get update 

lsb-release -id && uname -a
  

sudo nano /etc/apt/sources.list
sudo apt install git build-essential

git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git
cd backport-iwlwifi/
  

make defconfig-iwlwifi-public  

 

sed -i 's/CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS=y/# CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS is not set/' .config
 

make -j4
  

sudo make install
   

sudo modprobe iwlwifi
   

reboot
 

lspci | grep -i wireless

lsusb 
  

sudo apt-get update 
sudo apt-get upgrade 
  

sudo apt-get install wireless-tools 
   

sudo apt-get install  inxi wicd 
ls
 

ifconfig
   

lsusb
   

macchanger wlan0 --show
   

sudo apt-get install macchanger 
   

macchanger wlan0 --show
 

       iwlist eth1 scan
        sudo apt-get --reinstall git dkms build-essential linu-headers -$(uname -r)
    git clone

     https://kernel.googlesource.com/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/firmware/linux-firmware

    
    cd linux-firmware/



   

     ls
  

      make
sudo modprobe iwl4965
   

     sudo make install   

 

    sed -i 's/CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS=y/# CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS is not set/' .config
make defconfig-iwlwifi-public

sudo make install
   

sudo modprobe iwlwifi
sudo apt-get install network-manager

sudo apt-get install network-manager-gnome

sudo apt-get install wireless-tools
   

ifconfig
   

sudo apt-get install wicd
sudo dmesg | grep iwl

sudo dmesg 

sudo apt install git build-essential
  

git clone https://git.kernel.org/pub/scm/linux/kernel/git/iwlwifi/backport-iwlwifi.git
cd backport-iwlwifi/
  

ls
   

make defconfig-iwlwifi-public
   

sudo apt-get install make
   

make defconfig-iwlwifi-public
   

sudo apt-get install linux-headers-$(uname -r)
   

make defconfig-iwlwifi-public

  

sed -i 's/CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS=y/# CPTCFG_IWLMVM_VENDOR_CMDS is not set/' .config
  

make -j4
   

sudo make install
   

cd
   

sudo make install
  

sudo modprobe iwlwifi
   

reboot
  

ifconfig

**2 ethernet outputs are observed after this command.**

 - lokman@pardus:~$ `ifconfig` > enp16s0:
   flags=4163<UP,BROADCAST,RUNNING,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 > inet
   10.214.0.46 netmask 255.255.0.0 broadcast 10.214.255.255 > inet6 fe80::dac4:97ff:fef6:c3e9 prefixlen 64 scopeid 0x20<link> > ether
   d8:c4:97:f6:c3:e9 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet) > RX packets 23225 bytes
   32615000 (31.1 MiB) > RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0 > TX
   packets 10007 bytes 680944 (664.9 KiB) > TX errors 0 dropped 0
   overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0 > > lo:
   flags=73<UP,LOOPBACK,RUNNING> mtu 65536 > inet 127.0.0.1 netmask
   255.0.0.0 > inet6 ::1 prefixlen 128 scopeid 0x10<host> > loop txqueuelen 1 (Local Loopback) > RX packets 168 bytes 13356 (13.0 KiB)
   > RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0 > TX packets 168 bytes 13356 (13.0 KiB) > TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0
   collisions 0 > > wlp0s20f3: flags=4099<UP,BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu
   1500 > ether ea:de:cd:29:d5:00 txqueuelen 1000 (Ethernet) > RX
   packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B) > RX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 frame 0
   > TX packets 0 bytes 0 (0.0 B) > TX errors 0 dropped 0 overruns 0 carrier 0 collisions 0
```

[image]